# Showing the opened file in Eclipse package browser

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanted to enable a feature in Eclipse. When I use Ctrl + Alt + T or Ctrl + Alt + R to open a class or a resource file, I want it also be open and highlighted in the package browser. This way it's easy for me to check the version history, commit changes, etc.

My Eclipse 3 has this feature, but it seems to disappear in Eclipse 4.

Does anybody know how to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on icon "Link with Editor" (arrow left and arrow right) or select "Link with Editor" menu item in view menu (click on triangle icon in top-right corner of view and select). it works in Package Explorer and Project Explorer (Eclipse 3.x and 4.x).